# Extracting Values from 300 sheets where vlookup doesn't work

Tags: multiple-databases, vlookup

I have an excel spreadsheet which has just under 300 sheets in it.  The first sheet has a list of items which are all numbered 1.1.1, 1.1.2 etc.  The rest of the sheets have some of the items listed on them and not in numerical order.  I am trying to extract the quantity and total listed against these items on all the different sheets.

The sheets are complicated by the fact that they are not well structure so have section titles which are across merged cells.

I could get this information by hand using the search facility in excel and visit each instance of the number and then add up all the quantities and totals by hand.  Is there any way I can automate this?  i.e. by asking excel to take each unique identifier from sheet 1, find it in the rest of the sheets and return the quantity and/or total?

I tried using vlookup but it only seemed to return one of the values and ignore all the others.

Even if there was a formula that I had to change the unique identifier by hand that would be much quicker!

Thank you for any help you can give.  I am not a programmer so constructing the vb by myself would probably take longer than doing it by hand!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a $ before your lookup data for example

search - $A&2:&AZ&1000

then you are telling excel to look for anything in that array.

because if you do not have a $ in and you copy it, it starts excluding everything above that.